# show that there is no content on the page

Tags: php, mysqli

it is such that if I have nothing of entries from fms_opslag then it should come forward and say, "There are no entries at this time."

This means there will be an entry then it comes off but if for example there is nothing in the database must come forward and say "There are no entries at this time"

```
<?php
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('
SELECT fms_opslag.id, fms_opslag.title, fms_opslag.undertitle, fms_opslag.landsdel, fms_opslag.brugerid, fms_bruger.profilbillede, fms_bruger.fitness
FROM fms_opslag
INNER JOIN fms_bruger
ON fms_opslag.brugerid=fms_bruger.id
ORDER BY fms_opslag.tidspunkt DESC'))
{ 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $undertitle, $landsdel, $brugerid, $profilbillede, $fitness);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <tr class="postbox">
        ...HTML...
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
   echo "nothing here";
} else {
   while($stmt->fetch()) { etc.... }
}
```